# ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment still publishing empty folder structure

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

I have a File system publish pubxml file with the following lines:

```
<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
<DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
<AspnetCompileMergeIntermediateOutputPath>c:\btpublishtemp\</AspnetCompileMergeIntermediateOutputPath>
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  VSTemplates
</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

When the code is pushed to the folder, the VSTemplates folder is added with all subfolders. However, there are no files. Why does msbuild publish the folder at all? My `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment` directive should exclude it, right?

I end up with an empty folder structure like this:

```
\VSTemplates\Visual Basic\Templates
```

This folder is not included in my project or solution. It is checked into TFS within the web project folder. Here are the relevant MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=LB_Profile
```

Comment: Without using TFS, you run MSBuild command, did you still get this issue?

Comment: 1) When I run the same msbuild commands on my machine as found in the TFS build log, the issue does not reproduce.
2) When I right click -> publish from Visual Studio using the same publish profile, the issue does not reproduce.

Comment: I test the `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>` in my project and TFS, the VSTemplates folder could be excluded when TFS publishes. I can't reproduce your issue, does this issue happened on your other web projects? Could you please share a project sample which has this issue to [here](https://onedrive.live.com) for me to test.